# Auto Select checkboxes by comparing two array() JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, checkbox

I got some issues. I have a section with checkboxes that a person can check or not. If a checkbox is checked, the value is sent to a text field, and I store this text.

When the user retuns on the page, the textfield is already completed by the values checked. But the checkboxes are unchecked. So I would like to automatically check thoses checkboxes in JavaScript.

So I got 2 array with one which is the options and the other which is the options selected. And I would like to automaticly check the checkboxes according to the array target[].

I need to use JavaScript and no Jquery. So here is a template of my code.

```js
//array of options
//array of options
var array = new Array();
array[0]="January";
array[1]="February";
array[2]="March";
array[3]="April";
array[4]="May";
array[5]="Juny";
array[6]="July";
array[7]="August";
array[8]="September";
array[9]="October";
array[10]="November";
array[11]="December";

var target = new Array();
target[0]="April";
target[1]="September";


var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";
var t = document.getElementById('t');

// the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
for (var i in array) {
    //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
 j = i.toString();

 val = j;
 //cap will be the value/text of array[i]
 var cb = document.createElement('input');
 var label= document.createElement("label");

 cap = array[i];
 var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
 cb.type = 'checkbox';
 cbh.appendChild(cb);
 cb.name = cap;
 cb.value = val;
 label.appendChild(cb); 
 label.appendChild(text);
 cbh.appendChild(label);
  cb.addEventListener('click',updateText)
}

function updateText(){
  t.value = [null,...document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]')].reduce((s,el)=>el&&el.checked?s=(s||'')+el.value+'$#':s||'')
}

//document.querySelector('[name="March"]').click()
//document.querySelector('[name="September"]').click()
```

```css
   * {
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   #data {
       padding:5px;
    width:100vw;
   }
   .multiselect {
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:1px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:100vw;
    white-space: normal;
    height:200px;
   }
   .checkboxes {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:-1px;
    display:inline-block;
   }
      
            label {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    padding:5px;
   }
```

```html
  <a onclick="All();">All</a> | <a onclick="Selected();"> Selected</a>
  <form>
   <div id="data">
    <div class="multiselect">
     <div id="c_b"> <!-- Nous sert à réccupérer les valeurs des checkboxes selectionnés -->
      <div id="checkboxes"> <!-- Nous sert à créer dynamiquement les différentes checkboxes -->
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>

  <textarea id="t"></textarea>
```

I added this snipet if you can edit it to show me how to proceed, it would be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to set the checked property of the checkbox when you make it based on if it exists in your target array.

```js
//array of options
//array of options
var array = new Array();
array[0]="January";
array[1]="February";
array[2]="March";
array[3]="April";
array[4]="May";
array[5]="Juny";
array[6]="July";
array[7]="August";
array[8]="September";
array[9]="October";
array[10]="November";
array[11]="December";

var target = new Array();
target[0]="April";
target[1]="September";


var cbh = document.getElementById('checkboxes');
var val = '';
var cap = "";

var j = "";
var t = document.getElementById('t');

// the loop is creating the checkboxes with name, value...
for (var i in array) {
    //Name of checkboxes are their number so I convert the i into a string. 
 j = i.toString();

 val = j;
 //cap will be the value/text of array[i]
 var cb = document.createElement('input');
 var label= document.createElement("label");

 cap = array[i];
 var text = document.createTextNode(cap);
 cb.type = 'checkbox';
 cbh.appendChild(cb);
 cb.name = cap;
 cb.value = val;
  cb.checked = target.indexOf(cap) !== -1;
 label.appendChild(cb); 
 label.appendChild(text);
 cbh.appendChild(label);
  cb.addEventListener('click',updateText)
}

function updateText(){
  t.value = [null,...document.querySelectorAll('#checkboxes [type="checkbox"]')].reduce((s,el)=>el&&el.checked?s=(s||'')+el.value+'$#':s||'')
}

//document.querySelector('[name="March"]').click()
//document.querySelector('[name="September"]').click()
```

```css
* {
       box-sizing: border-box;
   }
   #data {
       padding:5px;
    width:100vw;
   }
   .multiselect {
    overflow: visible;
    padding:0;
    padding-left:1px;
    border:none;
    background-color:#eee;
    width:100vw;
    white-space: normal;
    height:200px;
   }
   .checkboxes {
    height:100px;
    width:100px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:white;
    margin-left:-1px;
    display:inline-block;
   }
      
            label {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px grey solid;
    padding:5px;
   }
```

```html
<a onclick="All();">All</a> | <a onclick="Selected();"> Selected</a>
  <form>
   <div id="data">
    <div class="multiselect">
     <div id="c_b"> <!-- Nous sert à réccupérer les valeurs des checkboxes selectionnés -->
      <div id="checkboxes"> <!-- Nous sert à créer dynamiquement les différentes checkboxes -->
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </form>

  <textarea id="t"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your setup, you will need to loop through all array elements to find matching values and then check the matching checkboxes.

However, I'd suggest a different approach: in target array, store the index of checkboxes. This way you have a direct reference.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer. But can you be more precise about what you suggest ? I'm not sure that I clearly understand. As I said, target will be updated according to a text field, and contains the value selected. Maybe if you add the snipet with your solution I would clearly see what you mean.